# Does etckeeper disrupt installations from Software Center

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, software-center

In the Software Center I searched for VirtualBox, found it and hit "Install". The installation ended with a Pop-up reading

> **Package operation failed**
>
> The installation or removal of a software package failed

and in the details section

```
installArchives() failed: fatal: $HOME not set
[master e1552a4] saving uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 793534 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-qt (4.3.10-dfsg-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run
```

Apart from this message it looks like the installation was successful, but this message unsettles me. The same happens when I remove it again through the Software Center.

After removing it through the Software Center I installed it from the command line without any errors or warnings using

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

The following line from the output of the Software Center is caused by `etckeeper` which leads me to think that `etckeeper` disrupts the installation and removal:

```
[master e1552a4] saving uncommitted changes in /etc prior to apt run
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
```

If this is true, what can I do to make `etckeeper` play well with the Software Center? If not, what else causes this issue?

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors shown in your details section log.  The first one at the very top ("`fatal: $HOME not set`") is due to git not knowing your `$HOME` directory after privilege escalation, and prior to the commit (before the VirtualBox install).  This can be fixed by adding the following near the top of the file `/etc/etckeeper/pre-install.d/50uncommitted-changes`:

```
if [ "$HOME" = "" ]; then
    export HOME="/root"
fi
```

You may want to commit this change with:

```
cd /etc
sudo git add etckeeper/pre-install.d/50uncommitted-changes
sudo git commit -m "Set $HOME if it is blank"
```

The second error ("`*** Please tell me who you are...`"), near the bottom, is also caused by git, and can be fixed by setting the user name and email for the `/etc/` repo owner:

```
cd /etc
sudo git config user.name "Your Name"
sudo git config user.email "your@email.com"
```

I had seen the same issues with my daily updates (on Ubuntu 14.04), however, they stopped showing up after I made these changes.

Hope this helps.